# Punch out area of shape using another—with translucent edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a ellipse-ish raster shape with a ragged, translucent edge. I'd like to use this to punch out the same shape (with the same ragged, translucent edge) from a photo, so that I end up with a photo in the ellipse-ish shape.

In Illustrator, I could use the Pathfinder "crop" tool, though not sure how I'd approach the translucent edges. Is this possible in Photoshop CS6? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Photoshop hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> and click on the layer thumbnail in the **Layers Panel** for the raster image.

This displays the marching ants around your shape layer.

Next click on the layer you wish to mask and then click the **layer mask icon** at the bottom of the layers panel.

I think you can also select `Layer > Layer Mask > Reveal Selection` from the top menu.